# Determining convergence of series when terms are decreasing by factor less than 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, ratio

Suppose that $a_n > 0$ and that, for n sufficiently large, $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq 1- \frac{c}{n}$$ for $c>1$

Prove that the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges.

**Hint supplied** : Prove the inequality $log(1-x)<-x$ for $0<x<1$

I'm not entirely sure how to approach this, the ratio test fails and I'm trying to show the series is Cauchy but to no avail.

Comment: That looks like “Raabe's test”

Comment: should this question be deleted since it is just the statement of a seemingly very well known result?